# Why does file:///android_asset stop working?

Tags: android, assets, android-assets

I have an app that uses some HTML and images for an informational activity. I programmed it a few years ago and it worked fine:

```
WebView wvManual = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvManual);        
wvManual.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/info.html");
```

However, when I open it now, I get a "Webpage not available" error, saying "file:///android_asset/info.html" is not available.

The files are there in the `assets/` directory. And according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html), it should work this way:

> Assets and resources are still accessible using file:///android_asset and file:///android_res.

Comment: needless to say but check for internet permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: My book comes in the form of an APK file, which makes extensive use of loading `WebView` content from assets. So, it definitely still works. There may be something particular to your HTML (e.g., something that might trigger a redirect) that could be causing the difficulty.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, turns out it was because I am using a library for most of the code and the assets need not to be in that tree, but in the app's tree.

Answer (score 3):

Found it.

I am using a library for most of the code (I have two apps based on the same source code tree, with minor changes) and the `assets/` dir was in the library. I moved it to the "actual" app's `assets/` dir and it works now.

Comment: Note that AFAIK, with Gradle for Android, the assets could be in the library. If that's not working now, it should be when Gradle for Android hits 1.0.